# java >> getProperty() to String[] >> foreach String[] = start class by name String[current]

Tags: java

Есть файл *"prop.poperties"* в папке *"%appdata%"*. Программа его загружает и читает значение переменной `run` в массив. В моей программе установлено 100 классов (`cmd001.class`, `cmd002.class` ... `cmd100.class`). Как запустить каждый класс, указанный в массиве (в значении переменной `run`)?

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
final String[] prop_run;
try {
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(System.getenv("AppData") + "\\prop.properties"));
    prop_run = prop.getProperty("run").split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < prop_run.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(prop_run[i]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Не удалось найти компонент программы:\n" + e1.toString(), "Ошибка", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
} catch (Exception e2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Произошла неизвестная ошибка:\n" + e2.toString(), "Ошибка", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
//И здесь будет команда запустить каждый класс
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой зверь "java.lang.reflect"

```
try{
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("mypackage/cmd"+prop_run[i])
    Object o = clazz.newInstance();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
  /*Обработка*/
} catch (InstantiationExceptione){
  /*Обработка*/
} catch (IllegalAccessExceptione){
  /*Обработка*/
}
```

а дальше приводим к общему интерфейсу и вызываем метод.

Можно конечно сделать и так `clazz.getMethod("main", null).invoke(null, null);`, но подумай хочешь ли ты хардкодить название метода в виде строки или писать такое уродство?

Answer (score 0):

Да, через рефлекшен можно, но если классы уже загружены, тогда можна их поместить с ассоциативный массив и проходя по нем вызвать нужный метод в нужном классе. Желательно что бы классы наследовали один интерфейс с методом `run`. Иначе прийдется опять обращатся к рефлекшену и искать нужный метод (что по моейму не очень разумно). Если классы загружаются динамически, подход тоже, после загрузки разширяеш ассоциативный массив (`Map<K, T extend IRunnable>` например) загружеными классами и индификаторами.

И того получаем два способа, рефлешкшен и другой))) Выбирать Вам.